# Binding of Label not working

Tags: wpf

my label is showing no content . what i am trying to do is i have a usercontrol TemplateForPlan and i am getting the selected item from that  usecontrol and after that i am coming to next usercontrol and that selected template name must be there in label content.

sorry for poor description . i am a newbie and just started to work on WPF.

```
<UserControl x:Class="ChaosMonkeyUI.TemplateForPlan"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="344" d:DesignWidth="424" Name="TemplateForPlanUC">
```

and this this is the label on another UC to show selected template

```
 <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=TemplateForPlanUC, Path=selectedTemplate.TemplateName }" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        Name="labelTemplateName" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,5,0,5" />
```

this is .cs file of **TemplateForPlan** and

```
public partial class TemplateForPlan : UserControl
{
    IList<TemplateType> template;
    public int noOfElementSelected;
    TemplateHelper xmlParser ;
    NewChaosSteps parentNewChaosStepPageForNextButton;
    public TemplateType selectedTemplate = null;

    public TemplateForPlan( NewChaosSteps parentNewChaosStepPageForNextButton)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.parentNewChaosStepPageForNextButton = parentNewChaosStepPageForNextButton;
        parentNewChaosStepPageForNextButton.EnableOrDisableNextButton("disable");
        xmlParser = new TemplateHelper();
        template = xmlParser.GetTemplates();
        listTemplate.ItemsSource = template;
    }

    private void listTemplate_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedTemplate = template[listTemplate.SelectedIndex];
        parentNewChaosStepPageForNextButton.EnableOrDisableNextButton("enable");
    }
```

and TemplateType is defined in other project and its defination is:

```
public partial class TemplateType 
{

    private TemplateRuleType[] templateRuleField;

    private string templateNameField;

    private string templateDescriptionField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("TemplateRule")]
    public TemplateRuleType[] TemplateRule {
        get {
            return this.templateRuleField;
        }
        set {
            this.templateRuleField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string TemplateName {
        get {
            return this.templateNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.templateNameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string TemplateDescription {
        get {
            return this.templateDescriptionField;
        }
        set {
            this.templateDescriptionField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

please also give some good link so that i can properly understand binding . i am very much confused in it.

Comment: Coul dyou add the code of the TemplateType class? My guess is that it doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: I don't see where you are creating a "TemplateForPlan" object.  You are declaring what it is, but you did not define one or create a visual element tree anywhere in that code.  The binding in your label can only access element names in the same visual tree.  Show more of the file in which you declared the Label.  You need to actually instantiate a TemplateForPlan object in that same file in order to bind to it.  And even then, in order for the binding to work you need to either implement a DependencyProperty or INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: TemplateType class is defined in other project.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bind to a field.

`listTemplate` is an items control, so it will have a SelectedItem property which you can bind to a property in your code behind.

```
public TemplateType SelectedTemplate { get; set; }
```

Then change your Label binding:

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=TemplateForPlanUC, Path=SelectedTemplate.TemplateName }"  />
```

(Notice the change in capitalisation of the name in the Path. If you post the XAML for your ItemsControl in TemplateForPlanUC then I will include an example that suits your case in my answer).

You also need to ensure you implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your control, and ensure that your `SelectedTemplate` property notifies in its setter. I won't detail that here because it has been covered a billion times before here on StackOverflow.